# Should I really replace java.security.PrivilegedAction in a migration from jdk 7 to jdk 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java.security

I'm reviewing what it involves to migrate a code previously compiled in Java 7 to Java 8, I found that on page https://java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml it mentions that "No methods can be called on the following classes: java.security. * "and in my code use java.security.PrivilegedAction;
My question is how could I replace this method? When I give * ctrl + click * on PrivilegedAction it sends me to AccessController which also belongs to java.security. I'm a little lost, I hope someone can guide me a bit, thanks.

Comment: ```WebEngine Limits JavaScript Method Calls for Certain Classes
JavaScript programs that are run in the context of a web page loaded by WebEngine ``` this is for WebEngine only, are you doing a project on WebEngine using javascript? If not that clause doesn't apply to you.

Comment: In fact I don't use that framework, thanks!